# Why does this code raise an UnboundLocalError? How can I fix the problem?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_alexa():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who the heck is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who the heck is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    elif 'date' in command:
        talk('sorry, I have a headache')
    elif 'are you single' in command:
        talk('I am in a relationship with wifi')
    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    run_alexa()
```

It causes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pears/PycharmProjects/SAINT 1.1/main.py", line 60, in <module>
    run_alexa()
  File "C:/Users/pears/PycharmProjects/SAINT 1.1/main.py", line 35, in run_alexa
    command = take_command()
  File "C:/Users/pears/PycharmProjects/SAINT 1.1/main.py", line 31, in take_command
    return command
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment
```

What is wrong with the code? I think I should use a global variable to fix the problem, but how does that work here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. We don't care about your level of experience or your current state of mind. We *do* care about a clearly asked question, using professional language, and with an appropriate title. See my edits for a guideline.

Comment: You should also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and try to diagnose and focus questions before asking. For example, in this case, clearly only `take_command` is needed to reproduce the problem, so you would only need to show us the imports needed for that function, the function itself, and a call to the function. Then you could check if it's possible to remove more and still observe the problem.

Comment: I think the problem occurs when the code runs in the `except` block. At that time, `return command` is generating the error. Try placing `command = 'are you single'` at the first line of `take_command()`.

Comment: That said, this is an easy one - and no, you don't need or want anything global here. I'll give you a hint: if the `try` block raises an exception, what value do you expect `command` to have? How do you expect it to get a value if the `command=` lines of code haven't been reached? (You should try to check what exception is being raised and why - this is why the textbooks tell you to look for specific kinds of exceptions instead of just using `except:`, and why they tell you to try to do something useful inside the `except: ` block.)

Comment: You should also try to make sure you understand what kinds of exceptions are plausible in that context. For example, what does the documentation say about `sr.Microphone()`? Does it mention any exceptions that might be raised? What do you think will happen if, for example, there isn't a microphone connected to the computer, or it's off?

Comment: `except: pass` is going to make debugging this code very exciting when something does actually go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pass` in the exception, you can return the command at the end of the try block

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)

            return command
    except:
        pass
```

BTW, I think the proper way to do is to return `None` whenever encounter exception.

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)

            return command
    except:
        return None
```

So you can have in the following `run_alex()` function:

```
def run_alexa():
    command = take_command()
    if command  is not None:
    ....
```

Comment: while this works,  I would suggest returning None in the case where it leaves the try by way of the except statement.   personally I like to see flow of control with single exit (except maybe an early exit when parameters are being validated before the body of a function runs.   My preference for understandability and maintainability.

Comment: Well now I'm getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pears/PycharmProjects/SAINT 1.1/main.py", line 62, in <module>
    run_alexa()
  File "C:/Users/pears/PycharmProjects/SAINT 1.1/main.py", line 39, in run_alexa
    if 'play' in command:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: I do not have your code but my guess is that you try to compare the string 'play' with command which is `None` . Please try to skip this logic when command is `None`.

Comment: How th do I paste the code, its too big, Im so new to stack overflow lol

Comment: So do I replace the 'play's with 'none'?

Comment: You need to put `if 'play' in command:` under `if command is not None:`
Meaning that after you check command not None, than proceed your implemented code, else skip any of these code.

Answer (score 0):

Your try block is throwing an exception before command is assigned in the block.  Your pass option on the except statement results in you ignoring the error.   It would be a good idea to print the exception.   I would suggest setting command to None before entering the try block so that it has a value indicating no value (None) if it exists without the code setting the value in the block.